# send parameters to each worker nodeJS

Tags: node.js

Suppose I have nodeJS cluster (master and workers). Number of workers is numCPU value. How can I send to each worker current data? 
For example I have array[1, 4].

1. First worker must get array[1, 2]
2. Second - array[2, 3]
3. Third -array[3, 4]

and so on. Then I want to use each part in function that every worker do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send messages to your children using `child.send()` and listen to messages from children using `child.on('message', () => {...})`. Vice-versa, you can send message from child to its parent process using `process.send()` and listen to messages from your parent using `process.on('message', () => {})`.

Here is the link to the [full documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback).

The same goes for cluster module: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle_callback

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  const worker = cluster.fork();
  worker.send({ some: 'data', arr: [1, 4] });
} else {
  process.on('message', data => {
    //do something with data
  }); 
}
```